# Will a Roomba always vacuum the whole room?

Tags: probability, algorithms, random-walk

This question, as indicated in the title, is motivated by the Roomba vacuum, but I am going to formulate it in slightly more mathematical terms:

Suppose that I am given a union $U$ of finitely many almost disjoint squares of area $A\in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, a point $p$ were chosen from $U$ randomly (evenly distributed). Finally, assume that I know if any point $q$ is within distance $\frac{\sqrt{A}}{2}$ of the boundary of $U$.

Can I come up with an algorithm to find a path that is piece-wise linear and will pass through each square once?

My initial thoughts are to think about this like a graph theoretic problem. You can construct a graph out of $U$ by treating it like a graph (corners as nodes) and taking the dual graph, which we will call $U^*$. This graph tells you about the connectedness of the squares. Then you start on a random node $v_1$ of $U^*$ and the probability of moving to an adjacent node $v_2$ is as follows $$ P(v_2|v_1) = \begin{cases} 1/n \quad d(v_1,v_2) > \frac{\sqrt{A}}{2}\\ 0 \quad\quad d(v_1,v_2) \le \frac{\sqrt{A}}{2} \end{cases}$$

where $n$ is the number of adjacent nodes with $d(v_1,v_2) > \frac{\sqrt{A}}{2}$.

Then you do the same thing for all the following nodes. The thing you would try to prove is that $\forall 1 \geq \epsilon > 0$, there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, after $k$ steps, the probability that you have been to every node is $1 - \epsilon$. But I have no idea how to prove that sort of thing.

Any thoughts on how to better approach this problem? (Or on how Roombas actually work?)

Comment: Do you want it to pass through each square *exactly* once, or *at least* once?  There are lots of possible obstructions to the former (e.g. arrange squares in a cross shape).

Comment: @NateEldredge I should have been more clear, I simply want at least once. A Roomba is more than welcome to vacuum more than once!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason to think that your region $U$ is connected?  If not, there's no hope.
If yes, note that a random walk on a connected graph will almost surely reach every node.

Comment: Since the cubes are "almost disjoint", we assume the union to be a connected space.

Comment: The real question is more about if I can bound the time it takes to reach every node with a given probability.

Comment: Then why don't you ask the real question?

Comment: Well, because by "the real question" I mean simply to say if I want to prove your statement about "almost surely reaching each node" I need to find some way to bound time. (I'm just reiterating the statement in the penultimate paragraph of the question).

Comment: The standard proof of this statement is via the elementary theory of discrete Markov chains.  There's too much background to expect someone to explain it all from first principles, I would say.  Durrett's *Essentials of Stochastic Processes* is one place to find an undergraduate-level treatment.  I suppose that one could extract the desired sort of bound from the proof, but it probably isn't made explicit.

Comment: You can prove an existence statement without providing a bound.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, that's very helpful! I'll look into that book.